# tomcat8 & eclipse mars nightmare

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, tomcat, debian

I've tried many different approach for installing a Tomcat server over a Debian jessie distro, for using it as server for an ecplise mars IDE.

The only approach thats works for my debian is to install Tomacat straight from they repo. 
And after some little tuning its seems that on localhost:8080 there is what I need (the page that says that tomcat works!).

After that I try to add it on Eclipse with the traditional steps suggested by many tutorial:

-adding xml and web tools support via INSTALL NEW SOFT
-adding the installing path folder to the server etc

Then when I start a new project and i try to add a server trough the "Servers" tab, the wizzard let me to choose the right server/adptor, but then there is some problem.

Instead of this:
[image]

I got this:
[image]

Where I cant edit the server's name and there a lack of a field, and no hope to hit finish or next.  How can I spot where my problem is? 
cheers

Comment: I think maybe Eclipse cannot find your Tomcat installation.  This is why it won't let you give a name and advance to the next step.

Comment: to me sounds like a permission problem, but I add the group as suggested on the tutorials

Comment: Maybe.  Do you need admin rights to edit, for example, the `server.xml` file?  Are you certain that your Eclipse can read and write files?

Comment: sorry, how can I check thise feature

Comment: ps. Same scenario if I open eclipse in "sudo" mode

Comment: This is as much as I can help without actually debugging your setup.  I hope an Eclipse guru will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to use your installed copy of Tomcat. As has been mentioned in the comments, your normal user lacks ownership of its installed location, and the layout may have been changed by the Debian packaging in ways Eclipse can't predict. Download a tarball from Apache, unpack it, and use that--remember, this is for developing your app, and you should never do that in your production server installation.

You should also check the [WTP Tomcat FAQ](https://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_Tomcat_FAQ) for other questions you might have.

Comment: may I can add the eclipse user to tomcat group or isn't enough?

Answer (score 0):

I found this on ubuntu's forum and with some edit about the version (mine is tomcat 8) works!!!! 
Thanks to all that point me in right direction

> Here's the way I did it, it keeps the system tomcat and your own
>   personal tomcat instance separate.
>
> Install tomcat as per normal: `sudo apt-get install tomcat7`
>
> Install private instance support: `sudo apt-get install tomcat7-user`
>
> Create local instance in your home folder:
>
> ```
> tomcat7-instance-create -p 10080 -c 10005 mytomcat
> ```
>
> Note: -p sets the port number (default is 8080) and -c is the control
>   port (default 8005), we set these so we don't compete with the main
>   installation of tomcat running as a service. "mytomcat" can be
>   anything you like, but it will create a directory by this name in your
>   home.
>
> Now use the following to make Eclipse happy:
>
> ```
> cd mytomcat
> ln -s /usr/share/tomcat7/lib
> ln -s /etc/tomcat7/policy.d/03catalina.policy conf/catalina.policy
> ln -s /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar bin/bootstrap.jar
> ln -s /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar bin/tomcat-juli.jar
> mkdir -p common/classes;
> mkdir -p server/classes;
> mkdir -p shared/classes;
> ```
>
> Now within Eclipse you can create a Tomcat v7.0 server and set the
>   installation directory as ~/mytomcat.
>
> Note: common, server and shared classes could be links too, but I
>   wanted to keep the two separate.